# Uncaught TypeError on Import

Tags: wordpress, import

All of a sudden, after doing a number of individual and organization contact imports, the import is erroring out on the second screen. I get a WordPress error that states:

> There has been a critical error on this website. Please check your site admin email inbox for instructions.

The error log shows the following error:

> Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Return
> value of CRM_Import_DataSource::getDataSourceMetadata() must be of the
> type array, null returned in
> [webroot]/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Import/DataSource.php:366

Up until yesterday, I was able to do the normal importing process. I have no idea what changed. Please help so I can continue importing!

`System: CiviCRM 5.55.2/WordPress 6.0.3/PHP 7.4.33 on Ubuntu`

Comment: Did you update your PHP to 8.0?

Comment: @PradeepNayak not knowingly. Should be running on PHP 7.4. Is this an indicator of it running on 8?

Comment: Confirmed - according the CiviCRM System Status page: `This system uses PHP version 7.4.33 which meets or exceeds the recommendation of 7.4.`