# Getting a TypeError: CRM_Import_Parser::getFieldMetadata() when importing contacts

Tags: contacts, error, import

We tried to update contacts with a csv file on CiviCRM 5.61.2, Drupal 10.0.9 and PHP 8.1.11.
We get the following error: `TypeError: CRM_Import_Parser::getFieldMetadata(): Return value must be of type array, null returned in CRM_Import_Parser->getFieldMetadata() (line 1768 of /home/ourcontext/www/crm/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/CRM/Import/Parser.php).`

The whole thing looks rather similiar to this other StackExchange question : [Uncaught TypeError on Import](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/43018/uncaught-typeerror-on-import).

I also found an issue which seems related, but which affects contributions instead of contacts: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/4317
Would a fix for that issue also solve our problem?

Comment: Are you importing data into custom fields?

Comment: Hi @LarsSG, thank you for your reply: At least one of the target fields in the import mapping is a custom field.

Comment: Did you try the import without the custom field(s) to see if that prevents the issue? Might help narrow it down.

Comment: It seems that the error was on our side: several of the fields were being mapped to "- related contact info -" instead of "- do not import -". What is not clear though is whether it used not to matter or whether there was an unintended change in the existing mapping at some point during an  upgrade to a later CiviCRM version. Anyway: thanks a lot for your time.